# How can I execute Python code without Komodo -ide?

Tags: python, ide, executable

I do that without the IDE:

```
$ ipython
$ edit file.py
$ :x (save and close)
```

It executes Python code, but not the one, where I use Pygame. It gives:

> WARNING: Failure executing file:

In the IDE, my code executes.

Comment: You'll need to add some more information to get an answer. Exactly what commands are you running to edit and then execute the Python code? What OS are you using? What's the error message you get when you try to run the code?

Comment: Amended my answer -- if something doesn't work in ipython, try with the real Python interpreter (just "python") before calling it a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something doesn't work in `ipython`, try the real Python interpreter (just `python`); `ipython` has known bugs, and not infrequently code known to work in the real interpreter fails there.

On UNIXlike platforms, your script should start with a shebang -- that is, a line like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

should be the very first line (and should have a standard UNIX line ending). This tells the operating system to execute your code with the first python interpreter found in the `PATH`, presuming that your script has executable permission set and is invoked as a program.

The other option is to start the program manually -- as per the following example:

```
$ python yourprogram.py
```

...or, to use a specific version of the interpreter (if more than one is installed):

```
$ python2.5 yourprogram.py
```